# A modular congruence of higher degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that for all $n$ naturals and $p$ primes, $p \geq 3$, it holds that 
$(1+p)^{p^n}=1+p^{n+1} \pmod{p^{n+2}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Use induction :

Let $(1+p)^{p^m}=1+p^{m+1}+rp^{m+2}=1+p^{m+1}(1+rp)$ where $r$ is an integer

$(1+p)^{p^{m+1}}=((1+p)^{p^m})^p=\{1+p^{m+1}(1+rp)\}^p$

Using  Binomial Expansion, this $=1+p \cdot p^{m+1}(1+rp)+\binom p2\{p^{m+1}(1+rp)\}^2+\cdots\equiv1+p^{(m+1)+1}\pmod{p^{(m+2)+1}}$